# Sqoop export inserting duplicate entries

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I am trying to understand how sqoop export works.I have a table site in mysql which contains two columns id and url and contains two rows

```
1,www.yahoo.com
2,www.gmail.com
```

The table has no primary key

When i am exporting the entries from HDFS to mysql site table by executing below command its inserting duplicate entries

I have below entries in HDFS

```
1,www.one.com
2,www.2.com
3,www.3.com
4,www.4.com
```

`sqoop export --table site --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/loudacre --    username training --password training --export-dir /site/ --update-mode allowinsert --update-key id`

So instead of updating already existing id its inserting duplicate id again (meaning two 1 , 1 for www.one.com and 1 for www.yahoo.com)

even if I remove the --update-key the outcome is same.Does its happening because the table doesn't have primary key

I am using sqoop 1.4.5 in Cloudera quickstart VM

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Sqoop [docs](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_upsert_functionality),

> MySQL will try to insert new row and if the insertion fails with duplicate unique key error it will update appropriate row instead.

So, either `--update-key` column should be **primary key** or have **unique index** on it.

---

Internally, sqoop will create query like this

`INSERT INTO table (id,email) VALUES (1,www.one.com) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE email=www.one.com`

and so on for all other values.

Comment: Yes when id = 1 then it will update the row however I am failing to understand why it is inserting a new entry again with id = 1.Am i doing something wrong.

Comment: @Deepak_Spark_Beginner as you said  `id` is not primary key. Did you create unique index on `id` field?

Comment: No my table doesnt have that.I will create it and then will try.Thanks a lot for a quick response

Comment: @Deepak_Spark_Beginner as I mentioned in answer, it will only work if it's  primary key or have unique index on it.

Comment: you can create index using - `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_1 ON site (id)`

Comment: will surely try that.Thank you

Comment: Yes after executing command 

sqoop export --table site --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/loudacre --username training --password training --export-dir /export --update-mode allowinsert --update-key id
and
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_1 ON site (id)
it works fine